# Laravel register section takes 120 seconds to load and opens very late

Tags: javascript, laravel

I just started using Laravel. I haven't written almost any code yet, the problem on my site is that it takes 120 seconds to load on the register page, there is no problem on other pages, but when I want to enter the register area, the page takes about 120 seconds to load, what can I do? I am sharing the code of register.blade.php for you.

```html
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="register-form-area">
        <div class="register-logo-area text-center">
            <a href="{{ route('home') }}"><img src="{{ getImage('assets/images/logoIcon/logo.png') }}" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="account-header text-center">
            <h2 class="title">@lang('Register Your Account Now')</h2>
            <p class="sub-title">@lang('Already Have An Account')? <a href="{{ route('user.login') }}">@lang('Login Now')</a></p>
        </div>

        <form action="{{ route('user.register') }}" method="POST" onsubmit="return submitUserForm();" class="register-form">
            @csrf
            <div class="row justify-content-center ml-b-20">

                @if($general->referral_system)
                    @if(session()->get('reference') != null)
                    <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                        <h5>@lang('You are referred by') {{session()->get('reference')}}</h5>
                        <input type="hidden" name="referBy" id="referenceBy" class="form-control" value="{{session()->get('reference')}}" readonly>
                    </div>
                    @endif
                @endif

                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="register-icon"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></label>
                    <input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="@lang('First Name')" value="{{ old('firstname') }}" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="register-icon"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></label>
                    <input id="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="@lang('Last Name')" name="lastname" value="{{ old('lastname  ') }}" required>
                </div>


                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="register-icon"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="@lang('Username')" value="{{ old('username') }}" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="register-icon"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></label>
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="@lang('E-Mail Address')" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <div class="input-group country-select">
                        <div class="input-group-append">

                            <select name="country_code" class="input-group-text input--group--select pl-1">
                                @include('partials.country_code')
                            </select>

                        </div>
                        <input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="@lang('Your Phone Number')">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="register-icon"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" name="country" class="form-control" placeholder="@lang('Your Country')" readonly>
                </div>


                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="register-icon"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></label>
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="@lang('Password')" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="register-icon"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="@lang('Confirm Password')" required autocomplete="new-password">
                </div>

                @php
                    $captcha = recaptcha();
                @endphp
                @if($captcha)
                <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                    @php echo recaptcha() @endphp
                </div>
                @endif


                @php
                    $captcha = getCustomCaptcha($height = 46, $width = '100%', $bgcolor = '#003');
                @endphp

                @if($captcha)
                <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                    <label class="register-icon"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" name="captcha" placeholder="@lang('Enter The Code Below')" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                    @php echo  $captcha; @endphp
                </div>
                @endif

                @php
                    $links = getContent('links.element');
                @endphp

                @if($links->count() > 0)
                <div class="col-lg-12 form-group text-center">
                    <div class="checkbox-wrapper d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center">
                        <div class="checkbox-item">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="terms_condition" required>
                            <label for="c1">
                                @lang('I agree with the')
                                @foreach ($links as $item)
                                    <a class="text-primary" href="{{route('links', slug($item->data_values->title).'-'.$item->id)}}">@lang($item->data_values->title) </a>@if(!$loop->last),@endif
                                @endforeach

                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endif
                <div class="col-lg-12 form-group text-center">
                    <button type="submit" id="recaptcha" class="submit-btn">@lang('Register')</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection


@push('style')
<style type="text/css">
    .country-code .input-group-prepend .input-group-text{
        background: #fff !important;
    }
    .country-code select{
        border: none;
    }
    .country-code select:focus{
        border: none;
        outline: none;
    }
</style>
@endpush
@push('script')
    <script>
      "use strict";
        (function($){
            var country = $('select[name=country_code] :selected').data('country');
            if(country){
                $('input[name=country]').val(country);
            }
            $('select[name=country_code]').on('change', function(){
                $('input[name=country]').val($('select[name=country_code] :selected').data('country'));
            });
        })(jQuery)

        function submitUserForm() {
            var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
            if (response.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-error').innerHTML = '<span style="color:red;">@lang("Captcha field is required.")</span>';
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function verifyCaptcha() {
            document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-error').innerHTML = '';
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you looked in the networking tab?

Comment: The one in register.blade.php? I'm sorry, I'm very new to laravel, I can push you a little :) https://www.hizliresim.com/3np19q8 you review the picture TTFB response time is too long –